# Starting out with forecast package in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am new to forecasting in R and am trying to automatically fit an ARIMA model to what I believe is a univariate dataset.

```
> str(p1.z)
'zoo' series from 2009-04-05 to 2010-10-31
  Data: int [1:83] 360 570 540 585 570 690 495 660 510 690 ...
  Index: Class 'Date'  num [1:83] 14339 14346 14353 14360 14367 ...

>  head(p1.z) 
  2009-04-05 2009-04-12 2009-04-19 2009-04-26 2009-05-03 2009-05-10 
         360        570        540        585        570        690
```

But when I try to fit the model, I get the error as seen below.

```
> p1.arima <- auto.arima(p1.z)
Error in nsdiffs(xx) : Non seasonal data
```

It is my understanding that the forecast package and the auto.arima function would be able to fit my data seasonal or not.  I am trying to learn time series forecasting and am using a dataset that appears to be ideal for this sort of task .  Also, the function ets() was able to find a model.

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ets()` and `auto.arima()` are not really set up to handle `zoo` objects. Although `ets()` is not returning an error, it will be ignoring any seasonality. `auto.arima()` is failing because it is confused by the `zoo` object with apparent seasonality. I will try to include better checking in a future version.

When using the forecast package, use `ts` objects instead. In this example,

```
x <- ts(x)
auto.arima(x)
ets(x)
```

That will ignore the frequency component of `x`. It looks like weekly data, so

```
x <- ts(x,start=2009+(31+28+31+4)/365,f=52)
```

will capture the frequency (and start period). However, note that `ets()` will not handle weekly data and will return an error with this latter formulation.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  2 quick things though.  I converted by zoo object to ts using as.ts.  That didn't seem to do the trick as I got the same error.  I then backed all the way up created a new object from the raw CSV, converted to ts using ts(object).  Functions ets and auto.arima both found model, but I got an error when trying to plot the fitted auto.arima object (Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ).  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: UPDATE.  Sorry, for the multiple comments. From the comment above, I didn't add the frequency portion, but that seemed to work for the auto.arima (and subsequently generated a great looking forecast) using the plot as found in your help.  You can probably tell I am new to R, but can you tell me why you add 4 in the start for April and not 5?

Comment: Weekly data is trouble anyhow, in my experience. Monthly data can have length-of-month issues and trading-day issues, but at least there are always 12 months in the year. And there are quite a few tools that aren't set up to handle weekly data, so you narrow your options considerably. I switched to monthly and saved myself a lot of grief.

Comment: You need to drop the frequency component in the zoo object. So as.ts() won't work. There is no plot method for Arima objects. For the start argument, Jan 1 is 2009, so Jan 2 is 2009+1/365, etc.